# How to add icon of the app on the home android screen (react-native)?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, apk

When installing on Android, it does not add a shortcut on home screen, but the app used to. You can find it in the app drawer only now. How to add icon of the app on the home android screen?

Comment: some hacks may work but there is no direct way for doing this on android .... but feel free to use android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT

Answer (score 0):

```
private void removeShortcut () {
           Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent
                .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");

        addIntent
                .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```

Comment: please explain this answer a bit :). code only answer are mostly not of much value. thank u! keep up the good work!

Comment: Where I need to add this code? (I don't know java, I'm working with react-native)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void addShortcut() {
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),                      MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "HelloWorldShortcut");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,

    Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this question years later, just ensure you declare a TV activity intent filter (`LEANBACK_LAUNCHER`) in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. This will ensure that it is identified as a TV app:

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

And include a home screen banner image (`android:banner`) which will be displayed on the home screen. [Image requirements detailed here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#banner):

```xml
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
  android:banner="@drawable/tv_banner">
```

This is documented in the React Native docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/building-for-tv, but it isn't very clear what the changes are actually for. The official Android TV docs help explain it: https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#tv-activity